# Rowencoder.apply and rowencoder.encoderfor methods in spark catalyst package

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-encoders

I am trying to create a dataset and I have RDD and a schema of structtype. In spark 3.5.0 and above the Rowencoder.apply method is been removed and have introduced new method called Rowencoder.encoderfor which will return agnosticencoder instead of expressionencoder . So what is the difference between those two encoders and is there any way I can I can cast agnosticencoder to expressionencoder

Dataset dataset=createdataset(RDD,Rowencoder.apply(schema))
But the apply method is not there in spark 3.5.0 and a new method is found called Rowencoder.encoderfor(schema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row method from Encoders class to get Encoder class object.
Dataset dataset= createdataset(RDD,Encoders.row(schema))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).